# SQL Default Values trouble

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008

This is a SQL 2008 Reporting Services Reports question!

I have a parameter called Doors that depends on another parameter called City in it's SELECT statement.

If you have one City selected, it will select all of that City's Doors and populate the Door parameter with them, if you have both selected it will select only options that match the previous City. Like if I selected Auckland City, then deselected that and selected Christchurch, the Door parameter will populate with only values matching Auckland City

In the database, the Doors table contains 3 columns, one for ID(char(4)), one for OfficeID(int) and one for Name (char(20))

Can I make the default select-all work without changing the database? Or what changes do I need to make?

Query for selecting doors and also the default values

```
SELECT [ID] + ' - ' + CAST([CityID] as char(5)) AS [DoorID] , [Name] 
FROM [dbo].[Doors] 
WHERE ([CityID] IN (@City))
```

What the Table being referenced looks like :

```
ID      CityID Name
'0001'  1      'Front Door'
'0002'  1      'Bathroom Door'
'0001'  2      'Front Door'
'0002'  2      'Garage Door'
```

Comment: I didn't understand anything of that..

Comment: Sorry about that, I've revised my post.

Comment: This is incomprehensible without example queries and schema

Comment: so nobody actually has any idea?

Answer (score 0):

What are you using for your Value field in the Doors parameter?  B/c if you are using ID, then you will see odd behavior (maybe as you have described) b/c ID is not unique, so if you were to use a composite value such as ID + CityID then you might resolve some oddities.  Do you have a copy of the RDL file to look at?

Comment: I am using the DoorID composite value, and I worked out that this oddity is likely nothing to do with how my data with laid out, but more because of when 'Default Values' are populated. They are only selected in two instances, when the form first loads, and when the previous selection is invalidated.
.
 .In the case I am currently dealing with, the selection is never invalidated unless you deselect a City you were previously selecting; Hence going from a single-City selection to a two-City selection will not get Default Values again.